# binary in md5 not working properly

Tags: php

I need some help, I get a accesskey from a gateway company that I need to append current year/month/day/Cref and then md5 hash it with a binary flag (true) set to it, php the moment I do it, the source behind file of firefox shows there is not `value=""` it does not work, the moment i remove the 'true' then there is a value, Is there something i am missing

Example of what I have to do.

```
$accessKey = "asringfromthem" . '/10/11/Cref';

$mdKey = md5($accesskey, true); // binary is a requirement from them
```

and in the html file i use

```
<input type="hidden" id="accessKey" name="accessKey" value="<?php echo $mdKey; ?>">
```

If i remove the true then there is a value in the viewsource of firefox but when i place it there then its not.

Am I going around the wrong way of doing it?

re-created question as the other one was little bit bad. :) Thanks for them that pointed it out for me

Comment: Can you show us what exactly the documentation says about the requirement for it to be binary? You can't really output binary values *in HTML*.

Comment: Deceze thanks for your reply, I have mailed them on asking why it is required they only say its required, and awaiting still on them. I have figured that out, since it is sending special characters and then they are saying they can't work with special characters, So I am stuck and hell. I don't know. :)

Comment: Can you show us exactly what the documentation says? You can't send the binary value, that's why we have the actual string representation of MD5. There might be a mistake on their end, all the APIs I worked with require just a plain hash. Have you tried to test your system with a normal MD5 digest?

Comment: N.B thanks for replying, Hell there documentation is limited to not existant, The moment I get a reply from them I told them about it, but awaiting a response, as there documentation is so bad, I also received outdated asp code from them I am not sure if asp.net has built in md5 but asp did not and they had a hand crafted script for doin it. So bad is my experience. Its sad

Comment: At least they replied and I told them about the binary that they wanted me to wrap in a htmlspecialchars since they did not want the special characters, they say they are looking at it. but if any can think of a way or have any advise i can give them I will much appreciate it. You all are stars. :) thanks for your replies.

Comment: But.. you can't send the binary. That's the problem. Binary means 1s and 0s. There is no character set associated with those bytes so my editor might show different characters to yours. That's why we have charsets, which display bytes as some characters on our screens. This is why people who created hashing functions came to conclusion that they could display bytes as numbers. But since those numbers were really big, they decided to display them as hexadecimal numbers. And that's what a MD5 digest is - it's a big hex number. You can revert it to binary easily. Get a different gateway company.

Comment: N.B. Your point taken, I am at that point of moving on. :) Thanks for your time and your replies, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The binary output is meant to be used by PHP internally, not to output in HTML.

You are probably trying to test your code to see the hash you get, this does not work.